# Complex nested filter in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this data:

```
{
    "someKey1" : "someValue1",
    "someKey2" : "someValue2",
    "someKey3" : "someValue3",
    "someKey4" : "someValue4",
    "projectParticipants" : [
        {
            "participant_id" : 1,
            "role_id" : 1
        },
        {
            "participant_id" : 4,
            "role_id" : 2
        },
        {
            "participant_id" : 5,
            "role_id" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to find items, that contains some project participants on some roles. For example I want to find item, where **man 1 on role 1** and **man 4 on role 2**.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use nested mapping and query for this.
You can read more on nested type [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html).

Once that is done you can do a [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

So after declaring projectParticipants as nested in the mapping ,a query like below should suffice -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "projectParticipants",
            "score_mode": "avg",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "projectParticipants.participant_id": 1
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "projectParticipants.role_id": 1
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "projectParticipants",
            "score_mode": "avg",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "projectParticipants.participant_id": 4
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "projectParticipants.role_id": 2
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, it's works! But can i use this in filter section?

Comment: Yes,  there is nested filter and bool filter. Just wrap them inside filtered query.